# Excel Iterate Loop VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through a column of data and change a text boxt to display the resulting data. currently this is my code

```
For index = 0 To 34 Step 1
    Me.txtLat.Text = ws.Range("F3")
    Me.txtLong.Text = ws.Range("G3")
Next index
```

however i want the "F3" to change to "F4", "F5" etc depending on the index. i'm sure its pretty simple just having a serious brain cramp.

I have tried the following but it didn't work

```
For index = 0 To 34 Step 1
    Me.txtLat.Text = ws.Range("F3+index")
    Me.txtLong.Text = ws.Range("G3+index")
Next index
```

i think i need to isolate the row number but not sure how... help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your close, but you will need to concatenate the `index` variable to the string like this:

```
For index = 3 To 34 Step 1
    Me.txtLat.Text = ws.Range("F" & index).value
    Me.txtLong.Text = ws.Range("G" & index).value
Next index
```

But this is a textbox so you will only display the last value.

---

If you want to add the item to a list in a combo box try this:

```
For index = 3 To 34 Step 1
    Me.txtLat.AddItem = ws.Range("F" & index).value
    Me.txtLong.AddItem = ws.Range("G" & index).value
Next index
```

You might also find that you need to clear it first so you don't get duplicate list.

```
Me.txtLat.Clear
```

Comment: and if i wanted to start at row three it would be index + 3?

Comment: Good question, I've edited the answer.  You can do that or you can just change your start index to three (second example).

Comment: this is returning the last value of the loop... maybe i'm using the wrong loop... i'm trying to return a value depending on the index returned. I have a combo box and when selected depending on what is selected i want to return that list index and reference that number in the column

Comment: I should have looked at your request closer, sorry.  Yes, a text box will only display one value which will be the last loop.  If you want a combo box then you need to 'add' the value.  Are txtLat & txtLong combo boxes or text boxes?

Comment: I figured it out Thank you very much... I didn't need the For loop as the index number was already calculated earlier in my program and i just referenced the index number with the range like you showed and used that to move through the range... Thank you very much for your help